# Using side inputs with tags (or how to use ProcessContext.sideInput() correctly)

Tags: apache-beam

Studying side inputs, I find that I can pass a side input to a ParDo using:

```java
myPCollection.apply(ParDo
  .of(myDoFn)
  .withSideInput("myTag", myPCollectionView)
)
```

I then wondered how, within the context of my DoFn function, I would be able to retrieve the desired side input?

I seem to see that the only way to get a side input in a DoFn is through the `ProcessContext` passed to the `processElement` function ([doc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.43.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.ProcessContext.html)).  The `ProcessContext` class provides a method called:

`sideInput(PCollectionView view)`

And now the question:

How can I get my PCollectionView from within my DoFn by tag?  What is the *purpose* of tag if not to be able to retrieve a PCollectionView by name (tag)?

What I am currently doing is using the same `PCollectionView` value *both* inside my DoFn and in the ParDo...withSideInput() and that feels like too tight a coupling.   What I am thinking is that my DoFn should have a logical side input (eg. "excluded_accounts" a list of strings) which is then specified at the ParDo creation with a tag:

```java
myPCollection.apply(ParDo
  .of(myDoFn)
  .withSideInput("excluded_accounts", myPCollectionView)
)
```

while today I am having to code something of the form:

```java
myPCollection.apply(ParDo
  .of(new MyDoFn(myPCollectionView))
  .withSideInput(myPCollectionView)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right direction, unfortunately you have to pass you side input in the `withSideInput` method of the `ParDo` and also in your `DoFn` class in order to retrieve it from the context proposed in the `process` method.

Example proposed in my `Github` repository :

[DoFn class](https://github.com/tosun-si/teams-league-java-dlq-native-beam-summit/blob/main/src/main/java/fr/groupbees/domain_ptransform/TransformToTeamStatsWithSloganFn.java) :

```java
@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext ctx) {
    try {
        final String slogans = ctx.sideInput(slogansSideInput);

        val ref = new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
        };

        final Map<String, String> slogansAsMap = JsonUtil.deserializeToMap(slogans, ref);

        ctx.output(requireNonNull(ctx.element()).addSloganToStats(slogansAsMap));
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        final Failure failure = Failure.from(pipelineStep, ctx.element(), throwable);
        ctx.output(failuresTag, failure);
    }
}
```

[PTransform](https://github.com/tosun-si/teams-league-java-dlq-native-beam-summit/blob/main/src/main/java/fr/groupbees/domain_ptransform/TeamStatsTransform.java) class that instantiates the `DoFn` with the side input :

```java
final TransformToTeamStatsWithSloganFn toStatsWithSloganFn = new TransformToTeamStatsWithSloganFn(
        "Add team slogan",
        slogansSideInput
);
final PCollectionTuple res3 = output2.apply(name,
    ParDo.of(toStatsWithSloganFn)
            .withOutputTags(toStatsWithSloganFn.getOutputTag(), TupleTagList.of(toStatsWithSloganFn.getFailuresTag()))
            .withSideInput("slogans", slogansSideInput));
```

Comment: Thank you sir ... I'll study further ... the area that is still confusing me is the passing of the tag value in your call to .withSideInput("slogans", slogansSideInput) ... I'm not yet seeing why we are passing in a tag ... for example, where (in your example), is the tag "slogans" used or referenced?

Comment: You are very welcome :)
There are several methods to pass `side inputs`  with beam `ParDo` : `withSideInput` for a single side input, `withSideInputs` with a list of side inputs and another method with a map of side inputs. I think the tag for a single side input, allows only to add an unique ID, but it's not used in the `DoFn` to retrieve the side input. To retrieve side input in the `DoFn`, we only need to pass by the current `processContext`

Comment: For exemple the implementation of `withSideInput` method in `Beam` : 

```public MultiOutput<InputT, OutputT> withSideInput(String tagId, PCollectionView<?> pCollectionView) {
            return this.withSideInputs(Collections.singletonMap(tagId, pCollectionView));
        }
```

It only calls and reference to the other method `withSideInput` that takes a `map` as parameter.